# Verify Solution inhomogeneous differential equation.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

i'm doing a problem that should be handed in tomorrow. One of the problems is a differential equation and i'm a bit vague(right word?) on these types of problems.I'll show all the steps i've done. We have;

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ + $\frac{1}{10}y$ = $\frac{2}{10}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = ($\frac{2}{10} - \frac{1}{10}y$ )

$\frac{dy}{\frac{2}{10} - \frac{1}{10}y} = dx$

$\int\frac{1}{\frac{2}{10} - \frac{1}{10}y}dy = \int dx$

ln $\lvert \frac{2}{10} - \frac{1}{10}y\rvert = x + C$

$\frac{2}{10} - \frac{1}{10} y = e^{x+c}$

$y = \frac{e^{x+C} - \frac{2}{10}}{\frac{1}{10}}$

Is this a final solution to the problem? i also have a starting value y(0) = 0 .

Comment: my exponents is "bugged". something wrong with my MathJax code

Comment: the exponents need to be between curly braces not parentheses. i fixed that. you can also write $e^{x+C}$ as $e^xe^C = De^x$ for some other constant $D.$ the work and the answer looks fine to me.

Comment: Your integral (line 4 to line 5) is not correct - you are missing a numerical factor. Check out the formula for the integral of $\frac{1}{ax+b}$. Also, your algebra from line 6 to line 7 has an error. You might also note that $e^(x+C) = e^xe^C=De^x$ where D is a constant, which you can determine from your initial condition..

Comment: it should be 1/(1/10) in front of my ln expression then. of course :)

Comment: But then there is a new problem. Can you show me the solution from the ln-expression?

Comment: 1/(1/10) = 10 so $10\ln \left| \frac{2}{10}-\frac{y}{10} \right|=x+C$ and $\ln \left| \frac{2}{10}-\frac{y}{10} \right|=\frac{x+C}{10}$ and $\frac{2}{10}-\frac{y}{10}={{e}^{^{(x+C)}{{}_{10}}\;}}=D{{e}^{^{x}{{}_{10}}\;}}$ for some constant D. We have assumed here that 2-y is positive so that ln makes sense, which is ok since y(0) = 0.